# Warning: Statemen has no effect; en programita C++ tipo switch

Tags: c++

Estaba haciendo un programa en C++, usando la función tipo switch

Pedía el precio de un artículo, lo leía, luego pedía la opción de descuento que depende del precio, pero esta opción de descuento se ingresa manualmente

Adjunto mi código para que me entiendan a lo que me refiero:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 

int precio, tot_pagar;
char opcion;

    cout<< "Ingrese el precio ";
    cin>> precio;
    cout<< endl;
    cout<< "Ingrese la opción de descuento ";
    cin>> opcion;
    switch (opcion)
    {
            case 'A':  tot_pagar = precio-precio*0.05;
                cout<< "El total a pagar es "; tot_pagar;
                    break;
            case 'B':  tot_pagar = precio-precio*0.10;
                cout<< "El total a pagar es "; tot_pagar;
                    break;
            case 'C':  tot_pagar = precio-precio*0.15;
                cout<< "El total a pagar es "; tot_pagar;
                    break;
            default: cout<< "Su artículo no tiene descuento";
    }
return 0;
```

Cuando ya inicia el programa, ingreso el precio, la opción, pero después no imprime la operación correspondiente según el caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::cout` espera recibir toda la información a mostrar en pantalla mediante el operador `<<`. finaliza cuando añades `;`

En tu caso, estás añadiendo un string, pero cierras el flujo antes de añadir también la variable `tot_pagar`:

```
cout<< "El total a pagar es "; tot_pagar;
```

Lo correcto sería:

```
cout << "El total a pagar es " << tot_pagar << endl;
```

Es recomendable también, añadir `endl` al final, para especificar el final de la línea.

Saludos

Comment: `std::endl` o `\n` cualquiera es valida.

Comment: `std::endl` o `\n` son ambas válidas siempre y cuando cada una se use en [el contexto adecuado](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5492605/499359). `std::endl` habitualmente es menos eficiente y más largo de escribir, tiene sus casos de uso, pero son considerablemente menos frecuentes que su uso.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente tienes algunos detalles como usar ";" en lugar de "<<" ya que no estas permitiendo agregar el valor de `tot_pagar`.

También puedes usar `cin.get();` para que obtenga únicamente el primer carácter (ya sea A, B o C).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
       int precio, tot_pagar;
       char opcion;

        cout<< "Ingrese el precio ";
        cin>> precio;
        cout<< endl;
        cout<< "Ingrese la opción de descuento ";
        cin>> opcion;
        cin.get(); //*** Haz uso de cin.get()
        switch (opcion)
        {
                case 'A':  tot_pagar = precio-precio*0.05;
                    cout<< "El total a pagar es " << tot_pagar;
                        break;
                case 'B':  tot_pagar = precio-precio*0.10;
                    cout<< "El total a pagar es " << tot_pagar;
                        break;
                case 'C':  tot_pagar = precio-precio*0.15;
                    cout<< "El total a pagar es " << tot_pagar;
                        break;
                default: cout<< "Su artículo no tiene descuento";
        }
        return 0;
    }
```